# CPU high load native_queued_spin_lock

Tags: debian, networking, linux-kernel, cpu, load

I'm using Debian 9(stretch edition) kernel 4.9., hp dl385 g7 server with 32 cpu cores. NIC queues are tied to processor cores. Server is shaping traffic (iproute2 and htb discipline + skbinfo + ipset + ifb) and filtering some rules by iptables.

At that moment, when traffic goes up about 1gbit/s cpu is very high loaded. Perf tool tells me that kernel module `native_queued_spin_lock_slowpath` loading cpu about 40%.

Who knows how to find the problem?

Comment: Have you ever managed to fix this issue? I also have a HP server here, and am having almost the same problem...